# How to save Listview item as a Text File

Tags: android, file, listitem

I have a `ListView` with SQLite location data ie: Latitude,Longitude and Location Address. I want to save the particular item to a file by clicking the list item. How can I do it? Please give me an example related to this or please explain how can I do this.

```
String latS;
String lonS;
String locS;
ListView list;

private ArrayList<String> kId = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> t_latitude = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> t_longitude = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> t_location=new ArrayList<String>();



list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3)
    {
        latS=t_latitude.get(position).toString();
        lonS=t_longitude.get(position).toString();
        locS=t_location.get(position).toString();

        Intent mIntent=new    Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?  saddr="+Latitude+", "+Longitude+"&daddr=" +latS+", "+lonS));      <<<<<<******* I have getting the values over here..*******>>>>>>
    }
});

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{

    final AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    if(item.getTitle()=="Save")
     {  
         try
         {
             File file=new File("/sdcard/data.txt");
             file.createNewFile();
             FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
             OutputStreamWriter out=new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

             out.append("Location: "+locS+"\n");
             out.append("Latitude: "+latS+"\n");
             out.append("Longitude: "+lonS+"\n");


             out.close();
             fOut.close();
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"file saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          } 

          catch (Exception e)
          {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
     }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to save contents of a listview to a text file in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060105/how-to-save-contents-of-a-listview-to-a-text-file-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you would need to get data in Strings.

```
String latitude, longitude, address;
```

These will hold your listview item's data.

Using data in these String, build a single String:

```
StringBuilder locationStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
locationStrBuilder.append("Latitude: "+latitude);
locationStrBuilder.append("\nLongitude: "+longitude);
locationStrBuilder.append("\nLocation: "+location);

String locationStr = locationStrBuilder.toString();
```

Add permission in manifest for writing to SD card.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Now to save the data in textfile, you would need to do:

```
try {
    File locationFile = new File("/sdcard/locationfile.txt");
    locationFile.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(locationFile);
    OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
    myOutWriter.append(locationStr);
    myOutWriter.close();
    fOut.close();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "location saved",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried this method but I m getting like this Latitude: null,Longitude: null,Location: null. Strings returning the values from database. In myOutWriter.append(locationStr); returns null.. Why?

Comment: Did you get Listview data in `String latitude, longitude, address;` before writing to file? @ReshminDP

Comment: Yes. I got the listview..

Comment: Not the listview. I am asking about Strings. You need to get listview's data in Strings. latitude, longitude, address should hold the data. Did you do that? Edit question with code.

Comment: Ya.. Getting the values in String latS,lonS,locS that I have declared here.. out.append() getting null values

Comment: Put a debug point at out.append and check values. Are they null?

Comment: getting null in out.append()    but getting values in list.onItemClick

Comment: Try this: Keep a global variable locationStr. And do this in list item click: `StringBuilder locationStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
locationStrBuilder.append("Latitude: "+latitude);
locationStrBuilder.append("\nLongitude: "+longitude);
locationStrBuilder.append("\nLocation: "+location);

locationStr = locationStrBuilder.toString();` . And use `out.append(locationStr);` and check. @ReshminDP

Comment: I got the error and fixed.. Thank you for your help @MysticMagic

Comment: @MagicalPhoenixϡ Hello, Let's say I wanted to add a line after each record. Am I able to do that? :)

Comment: Can't you simply use `myOutWriter.append(locationStr+"\n");` for new line? @20Cents what's issue?

Comment: Opps sorry my mistake. It was drawing a horizontal line after each record not open a new line :)

Comment: @20Cents ohk.. solved now?

Answer (score 0):

Anyway you can always create a JSON object that includes all the properties you need and use the JSONObject.toString() to get a text and use an OutputStream to write it where ever you want. To a file or to any other place.

Comment: I think that the suggestion to use JSON is an answer. He is looking for an example (MysticMagic gave one that personally I think is a bad one because I prefer to use standard format's for files so I will not be required to develop parsing solutions) or an explanation how can be done. JSON solution is an explanation.